# XAML WPF: Tab Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am currently prototyping a simple GUI program where I ran into what I hope is a quick fix with Tab Control customization. My tabs are currently set to "Light Sky Blue" when they are active. I have two tab boxes, and one of them I would like to change to Blue Violet. When I enter the code for the color in the area for the tabs that I would like to change, nothing happens.

Note for Code: I am trying to change the File, Options and Help tabs. You will be able to see in my code that I tried to set the background to "BlueViolet".

Let me know if you need a picture.

Here is my code:

```
<!---Main Class-->
    <Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="CartTools" Height="700" Width="1135" Name="Practice" FontSize="14" Opacity="1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!---Tab items for Cart customization-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border 
                  Name="Border"
                  Background="LightBlue"
                  BorderBrush="Black" 
                  BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                  CornerRadius="30,6,0,0" >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    ContentSource="Header"
                    Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <!---File, Options, Help tabs-->
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="TabControl1" Width="215" Margin="0,0,0,286">
            <TabItem Header="File" Name="TabItem1" Background="BlueViolet">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Height="28" Margin="6,6,79,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top">New</Label>
                    <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,40,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">Button</Button>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Options" Name="TabItem2" Background="BlueViolet">
                <Grid />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Help" Name="TabItem3" Background="BlueViolet">
                <Grid />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <!---Cart Management Tabs-->
        <TabControl Margin="251,0,12,12" Name="TabControl2">
            <TabItem Header="CartFunctions" Name="TabItem4">
                <Grid>
                    <RadioButton Height="16" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="RadioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120">RadioButton</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,28,0,0" Name="RadioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">RadioButton</RadioButton>
                    <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,50,0,0" Name="CheckBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">CheckBox</CheckBox>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Cart Configuration" Name="TabItem5">
                <Grid />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Cart I/O" Name="TabItem6">
                <Grid />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="CMS" Name="TabItem7">
                <Grid />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Blocking Database" Name="TabItem8">
                <Grid></Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thank you!

Comment: But when you want to see BlueViolet? If TabItem.IsSelected is True you set Background to LightSkyBlue and if it is False you set Background to LightGray. No chance to come up with BlueViolet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TemplateBinding` to get the local value from the `Control` in `ControlTemplate`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        ...
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then you will see two different backgrounds

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Background="LightSkyBlue" />
    <TabItem Background="BlueViolet" />
</TabControl>
```

If you want different colors only for `IsSelected` is true or false use `TemplateBinding` in `ControlTemplate.Triggers`.

Comment: It would probably be "least complex" to create this template binding and then remove the "false" IsSelected trigger to default the TabItem to be the Background color when the tab item is not selected.

Comment: I'm new to this language, so bear with me. Where it says `Background="LightBlue"` I changed it to `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`. Where exactly do I change `<TabControl>`? It seems like I have two tabs, but they're being controlled by one style.

Comment: You have a TabItem Style with Template used for all TabItems. At the moment your background is set only in ControlTemplate.Triggers. All other settings for Background will be ignored. Now it depends where and when you want to see BlueViolet. If I don't know what you want I can't say what you have to do.

Comment: I have it working now. I wanted to see Blue Violet for the tabs: File, Options, and Help.

Comment: The question was when: always or if IsSelected is true or if IsSelected is false. Anyway ... it's working now.

Comment: If IsSelected is true. Thank you.